# Can I apply a JS class to all HTML elements of a given type in pure CSS and JS (without any jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I would love to have an HTML document that does not rely on JQuery or anything in excess of standard JS and CSS where I can simply hide or unhide a specific set of HTML tags.  I guess by creating a class 'hidden' and an 'unhidden' one and then assigning them to the tags I want to hide or display, For e.g.  say I want to show all h1 and h2 headings but hide all h3 ones (whilst keeping the text on the same line as the preceding and the following text of the document).

```
    h1 { className: unhidden; }
    h2 { className: unhidden; }
    h3 { className: hidden; }

    .hidden { display: none; }
    .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
    .unhidden { display: inline; }
    .unhidden { visibility: visible; }
```

I have put together a whole document to mock this up, but cannot get it to work and am hoping I am missing something simple:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            h1 { className: unhidden; }
            h2 { className: unhidden; }
            h3 { className: hidden; }
            .hidden { display: none; }
            .hidden { visibility: hidden; }
            .unhidden { display: inline; }
            .unhidden { visibility: visible; }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Some unhidden text</h1> <h2>More unhidden text</h2> <h3>this text is **hidden**</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

The h3 tag still displays the text within it. :(  Any ideas?

Comment: To add, or remove, a class-name dynamically JavaScript must be used, to assign it dynamically on the server-side then a server-side language must be used. But this is beyond the scope of CSS.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS. And look up the `query` functions to select elements using a CSS syntax.

Answer (score 0):

assign ID to your h3 and then use it in the script:

```html
document.getElementById("myId").style.display = "none";
```

You also can use getElementsByClassName or getElementsByTagName;

Comment: That sounds great, so, I can do something like: document.getElementsByTagName("h1").style.display = "none";  I will try now, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Hiding all h3 for example:

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('h3')).forEach(function(el) {
  el.className = 'hidden';
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.unhidden { display: inline; }
.unhidden { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<h1>Some unhidden text</h1> <h2>More unhidden text</h2> <h3>this text is **hidden**</h3>
```